# Add shipping to PayPal simple chained payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained

I am using a PayPal simple chained payment flow rather than embedded for my website's transactiosn. Is it possible to allow buyers to choose their PayPal verified shipping address in the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there's no way (currently) to allow users to choose a shipping address from their account within an Adaptive Payments flow, however, you can use [SetPaymentOptions](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/setpaymentoptions-api-operation) to bind a shipping address to the payment if you have the user fill it into your app at some point.

You would call Pay with the action set to CREATE and then call SetPaymentOptions behind that to configure any additional options you'd like.  There are quite a few things you can add with that additional call.

Comment: This *looks* like it should work according to the documentation but I can't see this method implemented in the php-sdk https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php :(

Comment: Actually my mistake, it was added in last months release v3.6.106

Comment: FYI, I can confirm this method allows you to send through an address using Adaptive Payments. This will give your sellers coverage in the event of a dispute (as long as they have proof of shipment)

Answer (score 0):

No, shipping addresses are only supported in the embedded payments flow.

Comment: Here is an example of a simple chained flow without embedding...  http://imageupper.com/i/?S0400010040011S1360001964177700

Comment: This looks like Express Checkout, not Adaptive Payments/Chained Payments.  Can you give me some information on where you found this?

Comment: This is through the checkout swappa.com which states on their website: "Swappa makes use of PayPal's Adaptive Payments API. Technically speaking, in a Swappa sale the Seller is the primary receiver and Swappa is the secondary receiver in a chained payment."

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to have to call BS on that.  If you do a web trace when buying something from their site (using something like HttpWatch or HTTPFox), you'll see that they're redirecting you to `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=(hidden)`.  The "cmd=_express-checkout" means they're using Express Checkout, not Adaptive Payments.  (If they were using Adaptive Payments, it would be "cmd=_ap-payment".)

Comment: Interesting, maybe they changed their process. I guess I will have to explore embedded payments flow.

Comment: On my marketplace, I would like the buyer to provide payment to the seller, and then the website takes a cut. Additionally, I would like the seller to obtain the buyer's verified shipping address. Are there any feasible solutions to this?